# How can I set up a custom domain for an AWS S3 bucket with a domain purchased from Namecheap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, nameservers, namecheap

I am hosting a web app on AWS S3, but I am trying to set up a custom domain. For reference, I have followed this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

I believe I have carried out all of the necessary steps successfully, but I still cannot access my web app through my custom domain. I am aware that this is a duplicate question, however, I have looked through their solutions (such as making files public) but my domain is still not working correctly.

I am very limited when it comes to networking, so forgive me in advance. The following is what I have done:

- Created two S3 buckets, one which hosts the app and one which redirects to the app.
- Created a hosted zone on Route 53 and created an Alias, which points to my S3 bucket
- Copied and pasted my NS values (ns-xxx.yyy) into Namecheap's custom dns setting

From following the tutorial, everything should be working correctly, however, it is not. I have contacted Namecheap's support and they have informed me that my DNS settings have been updated. I have executed several commands (nslookup, ping and dig +recurse +trace www.example.com any) and each command is returning my AWS name servers. Therefore, because the commands are returning the name servers, I presume that I have correctly transferred them.

Also, for the last few days, whenever I have tried to access my domain, I have been greeted with a generic "domain is taken" message. However, when I try to access the domain today, I am greeted with a message informing me that the DNS server could not be found.

Can anyone help me with setting up a custom domain from Namecheap?

PS - I can access the app through the S3 bucket.

EDIT - I have executed the "dig +recurse +trace www.example.com any" command again, and I've noticed that there is no CNAME output if that helps.

Comment: You'll need to mention the domain so we can inspect it.

Comment: Name servers can take up to 48 hours to propagate. Do they names servers for AWS domain get returned in the dig command? Micheal is right, if we knew the domain it would be helpful.